# MySQL SELECT, JOIN, GROUP BY query optimizing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select DISTINCT products from within categories with category ids (1, 5, 12), ORDERED by cat_order + prod_order from MySQL database

**The problem:**

if a product is found in more than 1 category I need to show the first result,

ie: product number 1 is assigned to categories 1 and 5, I need to display product number 1 from category 1 along with its prod_order and skip the listing in category 5,

- essentually I need to display all products from category 1, than move on to category 5 and display all products from there, where product id was not shown previously, and move on to another category in the list (12)

if I run something like:

```
SELECT
    prod_to_cat.prod_id AS prod_to_cat_prod_id,
    prod_to_cat.prod_order AS prod_to_cat_prod_order,
    prod_to_cat.cat_id AS prod_to_cat_cat_id,
    prod_to_cat.cat_order AS prod_to_cat_cat_order,
    products.id,
    products.name

FROM
    prod_to_cat, products

WHERE
    prod_to_cat.prod_id = products.id
AND prod_to_cat.cat_id IN (1, 5, 12)
GROUP BY 
    prod_to_cat.prod_id
ORDER BY
    prod_to_cat_cat_order ASC,
    prod_to_cat_prod_order DESC
```

I get inconsistent results (product 1 will not be selected from the first category in the list), that is why I opted to select without "GROUP BY prod_id" and wrap that with another select which than groups by prod_id.

like so:

```
SELECT
    prod_to_cat_prod_id,
    prod_to_cat_prod_order,
    prod_to_cat_cat_id,
    name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            prod_to_cat.prod_id AS prod_to_cat_prod_id,
            prod_to_cat.prod_order AS prod_to_cat_prod_order,
            prod_to_cat.cat_id AS prod_to_cat_cat_id,
            prod_to_cat.cat_order AS prod_to_cat_cat_order,
            products.id,
            products.name
        FROM
            prod_to_cat, products
        WHERE
            prod_to_cat.prod_id = products.id
        AND prod_to_cat.cat_id IN (1, 5, 12)
        ORDER BY 
            prod_to_cat_cat_order ASC,
            prod_to_cat_prod_order DESC
    ) AS prod
GROUP BY
    prod_to_cat_prod_id
ORDER BY
    prod_to_cat_cat_order ASC,
    prod_to_cat_prod_order DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to find a more efficiant way to do this.

Table structure:

```
prod_to_cat:

prod_id | cat_id | cat_order | prod_order   |
    1        1          1           2
    2        1          1           0
    3        1          1           0
    1        5          2           4
    4        5          2           0


products:


id  |   name |  descr   |   price   |
 1    name_1
 2    name_2
 3    name_3
 4    name_4
```

each product can be in any number of categories, for example product id 1 is in categories id 1 and 5 in the example above.

Thanks a lot for any replies.
Pasha

Comment: . . You realize that your queries are grouping by one field (prod_id) and including other columns.  This is using a feature of MySQL called hidden columns.  The remaining columns come from arbitrary records within the group.  In particular, the prod_order has unspecified values, given your data.  Hidden columns are designed for the case where all the values are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [groupwise minimum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT   prod_to_cat.*,
         products.name
FROM     prod_to_cat NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   prod_id,
                    MIN(cat_id) AS cat_id
           FROM     prod_to_cat
           WHERE    cat_id IN (1, 5, 12)
           GROUP BY prod_id
         ) t
    JOIN products ON t.prod_id = products.id
ORDER BY prod_to_cat.cat_order  ASC,
         prod_to_cat.prod_order DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3696/2/0).

Comment: eggyal, thanks a lot for your reply, - Selecting MIN(cat_id) will not work as the list of categories is not sorted, - for example the list of categories can be :

5, 1, 12 

in that case I need to select all products from 5, than move on to 1 select all products from 1 excluding products that were displayed in 5, than move on to 12, etc...



In any case, - thanks a lot for your reply! - Any other suggestions?

Comment: @pasha: In that case, replace `MIN(cat_id)` with `ELT(MIN(FIELD(cat_id,1,5,12)),1,5,12)`.  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3696/3/0).

Comment: eggyal - It looks like it does it! - Thanks a lot! Can you please explain why this approach is more efficient?

Comment: @pasha: This query is correct, whereas your original query was not (for the reasons [@GordonLinoff gave in his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429238/mysql-select-join-group-by-query-optimizing/12429325#comment16709886_12429238)).  "Efficiency" (from a performance perspective) will come about from having suitable indexes on both tables, although it could be further improved if the priority of categories could be defined somewhere rather than calculated using `FIELD()` and `ELT()`.

Comment: eggyal, - Thanks again for your reply! And the categories are prioritized by the list itself, ie: the list of categories is in order how the products should be selected, for example if the category list is (5, 1, 4) than I want to select from 5 first and move on to 1 (the next item in the list), and so on...


So how can the query be farther optimized?

Thanks
Again

Comment: @pasha: If that ordering is always going to be dynamic and unpredictable, there's probably not much one can do.  I suspect we're delving into pretty insignificant micro-optimisation at this point anyway.  If the query as above is giving performance problems, your indexes would definitely be the first place to look.